# Open images in .cine file with Python module imageio

Tags: python, freeimage, python-imageio, highspeed

Using a Phantom high speed camera, the software saves an array of images in the '.cine' file format. This format is supported by imageio in python according to [the docs](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formats/index.html). So, I installed the FreeImage backend as described [elsewhere](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_autosummary/imageio.plugins.freeimage.html#module-imageio.plugins.freeimage) and tried to load the file with the following code:

```py
import imageio.v3 as iio
frames = iio.imread('<full path>/<filename>.cine', index=None, plugin='RAW-FI', extension='.cine')
```

But this yields an error:

> ValueError: Could not load bitmap '<full path>/<filename>.cine' : LibRaw : failed to open input stream (unknown format)

The file has a size of about 500 mb. All examples of the imageio docs I can perfectly reproduce. Any ideas on how to open a '.cine' file in python?

A last resort would be to circumvent this issue altogether and convert the images to another format using the proprietary software (Windows only...), but loading the pictures directly from the .cine file in python would be preferred.

Comment: Hard to say without access to the file. FreeImage has, unfortunately, not seen a new release since 2018 so it could simply be that your version of the CINE file is too new. On the other hand, it could also be a bug, in which case you could/should open an Issue in the ImageIO repo :)

Comment: I see, when I will do more experiments I might consider investing more time into opening these files in a python environment. For now, I was pragmatic and just converted the file to mp4 using the Phantom CineViewer on a Windows machine. Not ideal, but it served my purpose.